# Как получить binding path в из кода в wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

Есть такой XAML-код:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="fulllist">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=id}" IsReadOnly="True" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=addTime}" IsReadOnly="True" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=key}" IsReadOnly="True" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Как получить значение Binding Path конкретного столбца в зависимости от неких условий?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например, так:

```
foreach (var col in fulllist.Columns)
{
    var dataBoundColumn = col as DataGridBoundColumn;
    if (dataBoundColumn == null)
        continue;
    var bindingBase = dataBoundColumn.Binding;
    Binding binding = bindingBase as Binding;
    if (binding == null) // ещё может быть, например, MultiBinding
        continue;
    var path = binding.Path;
    // у вас есть путь, делайте с ним что хотите
}
```